# ReactJS catch HTTP error

Tags: reactjs, fetch

I have the next problem: I made authentication using Spring Security and after entering incorrect data, it(java server) sends HTTP 401 status code.[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wLVMx.png)

I can't catch this exception. I'm using fetch API, but catch doesn't work and response.status too. How can I solve this?

```js
login = (event) => {
  event.preventDefault();
  var data = {username: this.refs.username.value, password: this.refs.password.value};
  var that = this;
  fetch('http://localhost:8080/login',{
    method: 'POST',
    mode: "no-cors",
    body: JSON.stringify(data),
    headers:{
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    }
  }).then( (response) => {
    console.log(response);
    if (response.status !== 200) {
      console.log('Looks like there was a problem. Status Code: ' +
        response.status);
    } else {
      console.log('Yeeee man, you can login');
      this.props.history.push('/');
    }
  }).catch(error => console.log('Error ' + error));
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. The problem was in mode: 'no-cors'. It means that I can send the request but I will not be able to read the response... So I needed to enable cors in java.

Answer (score 0):

Check the object first `console.log(response.status)` or try use `response.data.status`

Sometimes the response is placed inside the object `data`

Comment: I checked. Status is 0, when I try response.data.status I get Error TypeError: Cannot read property 'status' of undefined

Comment: Try response.data.headers

Comment: Or try console.log(response)

Comment: Error TypeError: Cannot read property 'headers' of undefined. I tried log only response and it is empty, there is nothing interesting

Comment: Check your restful code again. If your request success a data will passing into response object

Comment: I think it's not in my power) spring framework does it itself, it only sends status

Comment: It's weird, I know. I would like to send a response, but I think I can't